# Add VPC Configuration in Kinesis Data Analytic App via aws cdk

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I am trying to create AWS Kinesis Data Analytic(KDA) App via cdk. I need to put this KDA app inside a VPC but I am not able to find any cloudformation(cdk) support to add it. I can see vpc configiration api is exposed by aws kinesis sdk but it is not exposed via cdk. Anybody has any references on how to do it. Please do share the code or documentation reference